# Install Second Copy of Windows in a Partition, Block Access to other Partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I want to lend my computer to my flatmate so that he can play some games for which his computer is underpowered.

Is it possible to install a second copy of Windows 7 into a separate partition and configure it such that it has no access to the other partitions and disks on the computer, the ones that I use in my main Windows install?

I'm not concerned about security, just want to avoid him accidentially messing with my data somehow.

Can I do that?

Comment: This is overkill.  You are using a _multi-user_ operating system that has access control capabilities.

Comment: but that won't really safe my stuff if he manages to catch a virus or so. i'd really like to set it up so that it touches as less as possible of my current configuration.

Comment: Yes, it will.  A virus executing as him will only be able to do what you've already let him do with _any other_ program.  Viruses are not magic.  If you want to deny access to your "current configuration" then use [the access control facilities that your multi-user operating system gives to you](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc722655.aspx) **for the very purpose** of insulating one user from another.

Comment: yeah but as he needs to install games and stuff, he needs admin rights

Answer (score 2):

Not completely, but you can encrypt your hard drive partition with TrueCrypt if you are concerned about security. You can also try going into Disk Management, right-clicking on the other partitions, and going to Change Drive Letters and Paths, and removing the drive letter. It will prevent them from showing up in My Computer, but he can re-mount them if he knows how

Answer (score 0):

Have him buy a hard drive - while the prices are going up during the shortage, they are still fairly cheap (and get an appropriate caddy if necessary) and just swap out the drives.  Alternatively, you can install another copy of Windows to a VHD... though that will affect performance SLIGHTLY.